# Pulling Column Names into Excel from SQL query

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I'm using Excel to pull data from an SQL db. I used the code from another SO question and it works fine. Now I want to pull in the column names from a table in addition to the actual table. I figured out that I could get the names using the For Each fld loop. However there's still the issue of populating them horizontally in a row in Excel as the number of columns might change - so I'm thinking I would need another For each loop also or something similar.

```
Sub GetDataFromADO()

'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;User ID=abc;Password=abc;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyCmd.CommandText = "select * from myTable"
    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    objMyCmd.Execute

'Loop Names'
    ' WHAT TO DO HERE????'

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you want the headers lined up with the data?  The data starts in A1, but you seem to have set the header range to A4.

Comment: yeah you're right - bad copy and paste on my part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out after 4 attempts, here's the code for the loop.

```
 'Loop'
 Dim FieldRange As Range
 Set FieldRange = Range("A4")
 Set TableColumns = Range("A4:H4")
 x = 1

 Range("A4").Select

 For Each fld in objMyRecordset.Fields
      ActiveCell.Value = fld.Name
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).Select
      x = x + 1 'tick iterator
 Next

 ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset
 Range("A4").Select
```

Comment: You don't need to select the Cell use something like `Range("A4").OffSet(0, x).value = fld.Name`

Answer (score 24):

My usual code is very similar:

```
For intColIndex = 0 To objMyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1 
    Range("A4").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next
```

Comment: I like the "shortness" of your solution. I just expanded it a bit to set the headers to Bold.

Comment: I am baffled at the absence of a solution which does not resort to a loop.

Answer (score 8):

To make it super simple, do something like this (using Sheet1 and recordset r)

```
    For i = 0 To r.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheet1.Cells(1, i + 1) = r.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just set your "x" variable to 0 and then do something like:

```
x = 0

For Each Field In RS.Fields 'RS being my Recordset variable
    Range("A3").Offset(0, x).Value = Field.Name
    x = x + 1
Next Field
```

And that will make it a bit easier to read... :)

Comment: Isn't this answer DAO instead of ADO?